# A clean way to set a daily running time for a program

Tags: cron, date, services, init, sysvinit

Kind of a noob question but I'm looking to have my networking daemon (wicd), run every day on my machine, only from 5am-6am and 6pm-7pm, regardless of when my machine was turned on, in other words, if the process is running while it's not that time of the day, I need it to terminate. What would be the least hacky way to do this.
Obviously if I use crontab and write a cronjob where wicd is run at 5am and 6pm, and e.g. killall gets rid of it at 6am and 7pm, this would cause a problem, because if I start my machine at 5:04am wicd will not run initially, so I could make wicd run, or not run, at init time by writing an init script for it (my init's SysV), where I check the current time of day, this seems like it should cut it, but is this workaround the only way to approach this issue, or is there a simpler way to make sure the program is running only at the specified time regardless of the time my machine was turned on.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use [CFEngine](https://cfengine.com/product/community/), with a policy approximately like so:

```
bundle agent mybundle {

  services:
    Hr5|Hr18::
      "wicd"
        service_policy => "start";

    !(Hr5|Hr18)::
      "wicd"
        service_policy => "stop";

}
```

The default CFEngine run interval is every five minutes (with a delay in there so a fleet of hosts won't all have it run at the same moment), so in your example, after starting your computer at 5:04 a.m., within 5 minutes the service would be running.  Then on the next run of CFEngine after 6:00 a.m. (sometime between 6:00 and 6:05), the service would be stopped.